# Derivation with respect to cumulative distribution function

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am trying to understand the how Baye, Kovenock and Vries 2008 calculate the 
derivative of E(w).

F is a symmetric mixed-strategy equilibria with density f(x) on some subset (m,u) of the support of F (so that there are no mass points in this interval).

I am purely interested in the step by step derivation from $E(w)$ to $\frac{dE(w)}{d(w)}$, which I can not understand.

$w \exists(m,u)$

$W(x_i,x_j)=v-\beta x_i - \delta x_j$

$L(x_i,x_j)=-\gamma-\alpha x_i - \theta x_j $

$E(w)=\int_{0}^{w}W(w,x)dF(x) + \int_{w}^{\infty}L(w,x)dF(x)$

$\frac{dE(w)}{dw}=[v+\gamma + (\alpha+\theta-\beta-\delta)w]f(w)-\alpha+(\alpha-\beta)F(w)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{w}W\left(w,x\right)dF\left(x\right)=\left(v-\beta w\right)\int_{0}^{w}dF\left(x\right)-\delta\int_{0}^{w}xdF\left(x\right)=\left(v-\beta w\right)F\left(w\right)-\delta\int_{0}^{w}xdF\left(x\right)$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $w$ gives:

$-\beta F\left(w\right)+\left(v-\beta w\right)f\left(w\right)-\delta wf\left(w\right)=-\beta F\left(w\right)+\left(v-\beta w-\delta w\right)f\left(w\right)$

$\int_{w}^{\infty}L\left(w,x\right)dF\left(x\right)=\left(-\gamma-\alpha w\right)\int_{w}^{\infty}dF\left(x\right)-\theta\int_{w}^{\infty}xdF\left(x\right)=\left(-\gamma-\alpha w\right)\left(1-F\left(w\right)\right)-\theta\int_{w}^{\infty}xdF\left(x\right)$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $w$ gives:

$\left(-\alpha\right)\left(1-F\left(w\right)\right)+\left(\gamma+\alpha w\right)f\left(w\right)+\theta wf\left(w\right)=\alpha F\left(w\right)-\alpha+\left(\gamma+\alpha w+\theta w\right)f\left(w\right)$

Then addition gives the formula you mention.